# How does the game difficulty increase in co-op mode?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Compared to single player mode, do enemies in co-op mode (both Campaign and Whored mode) become tougher or deal more damage? By how much? What about their numbers? I'm also curious about what changes in missions, including the DLC missions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Compared to single player mode, do enemies in co-op mode (both
>   Campaign and Whored mode) become tougher or deal more damage?

I don't think so.

> What about their numbers?

I believe that the amount of enemies also remains the same.

> I'm also curious about what changes in missions, including the DLC
>   missions

Nothing.

---

A few ways that I know that the difficulty increases:

- *Guardian Angel* activity, guarding a car by helicopter and rocket
  launchers. One of the biggest dangers to these VIP cars is friendly
  fire. More car-guards mean more chance of friendly fire.
- *No man behind*: If one of you dies, you fail the mission.
- *Transport*: In missions with at least one homie, it's harder to take a coupe (two-seater) vehicle, since that leaves one out.
- *Insurance Fraud*: The monetary goal is doubled.
- *Friendly fire*: Itself.
- *Notoriety*: You share notoriety.
  "Sweet, an Attrazione! ... Dude, I can't store it because of notoriety."
  "Sorry, I accidentally an old lady/civilian/police officer/gang member."
  Both of you need to be in a store that you own (individually) to shake notoriety in this way.
- *Mayhem (Mission)* Target gets raised to 200,000.

Answer (score 3):

#### Campaign

---

While it may not be exactly what you are asking, in my experience co-op campaign is significantly easier than single player (although neither was particularly challenging at higher levels, due to unlocked buffs).  I never noticed an increase in enemy damage or quantity for missions, timed gang battles, or just free for all fights in the street.

Instead, when you've got a buddy you always have the power to split up enemies, pack twice the firepower, and the ability to bring a superhuman from later in the game to fights earlier in the plotline where your character is much weaker.  Recall that by end game your character is ***basically unkillable***, so having such a character for a pal can really never be called "harder" in my opinion.  Even if your friend has not yet become ***literally bulletproof*** they may still have power vehicles and weapons which you can make use of - such as the ability to call the helicopter or VTOL homie.

Also, there are a number of "Co-op" style missions with the helicopter or the flame retardant suits, which are actually ***very challenging*** when playing solo - simply because of targeting difficulty while driving a vehicle.  Having a co-op companion for these missions is not only helpful, but for the highest levels may be borderline required - not really because of enemy hitpoints or quantity, just because of timed missions and low tolerance for targeting errors.

#### The odd case of "Whored Mode"

---

In a riff on Gears of War, SR3 includes a separate horde mode with totally different rules.  For deep details, [see the wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Whored_Mode).  A few key aspects are:

- You can't play with your "customized" Campaign (pronounced *god-like*) character.  This makes you significantly weaker, and vulnerable to the unique rules of each wave.
- Like campaign missions if you play Co-op and you get downed, your buddy can help you up within 30 seconds and you'll keep going.  This one ability makes a big difference, and would arguably make Co-op the easier mode under any circumstances.

I do not recall any difficulty scaling associated with Co-op "Whored Mode", but if there is any it's not really noticeable. As a side note, don't waste too much time in this mode - the campaign is way more fun.

Comment: Know how it affects 'Whored Mode' co-op? (editing this into my question)

Comment: Whored Mode is a different animal, possibly a whole different question.  In Whored Mode you can't bring in your customized character, which has major implications.  I don't recall any increased difficulty with two players, but I rarely played that mode.  A quick look [at the wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Whored_Mode) has lot's of details, but makes no mention of difficulty scaling.  It does mention the important aspect that "*When playing in co-op, a downed player has thirty seconds to be revived by the other player before they die.*"

Comment: I had forgotten to mention that additional key advantage.  I can edit my answer, if any of that is helpful to you.  Alternatively, you could ask a separate question, since the scope of this one is getting kind of large.  Up to you.

Comment: I'll just make this question cover both Campaign and Whored mode, so just edit in any info you have for Whored Mode.